# Django session not persisting with generic views

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views, django-sessions

```
class IndexTemplateView(TemplateView):
    '''Index TemplateView.'''

    template_name = 'frontend/index.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Manages credentials received for methods calling authentication.'''

        bitrix24_domain = request.GET.get('DOMAIN')
        request.session['bitrix24_domain'] = bitrix24_domain
        print(request.session['bitrix24_domain']) # String is stored and printed to the screen.
        return redirect('index')

    # Bitrix24 sends credentials via POST right after GET request.
    # CSRF protection would cause error in this case.
    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class LoginTemplateView(TemplateView):
    '''Login TemplateView.'''

    template_name = 'frontend/login.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Renders the login page.'''

        redirect_uri = get_google_redirect_uri()
        print(request.session.items()) # Returns empty session. The string was never saved.
        return redirect(redirect_uri)
```

I've tried setting `request.session.modified = True` but it didn't work either. I really don't know why I can't store a string in session. I've also tried to store in `self.request` within the POST request, but without success, tried to store it in the dispatch() function, in the setup() function. Tried almost everything and I can't store a single piece of information in my session. I'm also using Django Rest framework.

Can anyone help me on how to use sessions with generic views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, session does not work with tunneling service as Ngrok.